Can two people sign a agreement without a lawyer
So can two people sign a known sperm donor agreement they make themselves without lawyers if they have a witness and it's for at home insemination in Maine we don't want to get lawyers involved and we can't afford to were friends.

Even if you legally can, it's probably not a good idea. Lawyers will make sure that all the i's are dotted and t's crossed. Doing it yourself is a recipe for problems later on.

Consider it like getting married without a prenuptial agreement.  And FWIW, a written agreement doesn't guarantee a court will agree with it years later:  https://www.boydlawlosangeles.com/do-sperm-donors-pay-child-support/

These particular kinds of agreements are subject to considerable regulation that is not consistent from state to state. The likelihood that a sperm donor agreement would be held valid for paternity purposes without strictly adhering to the state law on the subject without the help of a lawyer is very low.

The primary Maine Statute on point is https://legislature.maine.gov/statutes/19-A/title19-Ach61.pdf

Put another way, the title question is easy. The prudence of the course of action in the body and the specific considerations that this special kind of contract presents are involved and not easy.

Yes - two people can make a contract between them and it be purely verbal or it can be memorialized in writing.
Some contracts are required to be in writing like copyright transfers and often real estate transactions.
Without professional advice you run many risks including having an ambiguous agreement, an unenforceable agreement or one that doesn’t actually say what one or the other or both parties think it says.

A lawyer could say if the agreement is lawful. If it isn't it will have no effect, or only partial effect. Also, "oral" is a better word than "verbal" because verbal means expressed in words, which could be written words.

@GerardAshton Except that in the English vernacular most people presume a "verbal agreement" means the spoken word, which is not the same thing as written.  Because if there is a written agreement most people would just call it that. (and "oral" could pertain to guttural sounds, halitosis, dentistry, etc...)

Yes, and most contracts are agreed upon that way!
Did you ever start up a new phone, computer or installed software? Then you agreed to a contract in the shape of the EULA. You ever signed up for a webpage or social media? Same, it's a contract. Did you ever buy something in a store? That's a contract, and no lawyer in sight! Do you have work? Probably you either have a verbal contract, or even signed some paperwork. And no lawyer was needed!

Actually, in most/all of the examples you provide lawyers were most definitely involved, at least from one party. Almost all subscriptions, EULAs, open source licenses, conditions of sale, web site ToS, and many employment contracts - written by lawyers.
